# Is there something wrong with my react parent class?

Tags: reactjs

I am practicing using react to build a simple table. Here my table has three columns. (name, job, delete). There is already some data in the table. In the third column, I want to build a button so the user can click and cancel the whole row

I already fixed several bugs but the table still does not show up

```
const TableBody = props => { 
    const rows = props.fillTheData.map((row, index) => {
        return (
            <tr key={index}>
                <td>{row.name}</td>
                <td>{row.job}</td>
                <td><button onClick={() => props.removeCharacter(index)}>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        );
    });

    return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
        character : [ ] 
    };

    removeCharacter = index => {
        const {character} = this.state;

        this.setState({
            character: character.filter((element, i) => { 
                return i !== index;
            })
        });
    }

    handleSubmit = character => {
      this.setState({character:[...this.state.character,character]})
    }

  render() {

    return(
        <div class= "container">
          <Table characters = {this.state.character} removeCharacter = {this.removeCharacter} />
          <Form handleSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}/>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super( props );

    this.initialState = {
      name: '',
      job: ''
    };

    this.state = this.initialState;
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    const{name,job} = event.target;

    this.setState(
    {
      [name]: value
    }
    );
  }

  submitForm = () => {
    this.props.handleSubmit(this.state);
    this.setState(this.initialState);
 }

  render() {
    const { name, job } = this.state; 

    return (
      <div class="container2">
        <form>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input 
                type="text" 
                name="name" 
                value={name} 
                onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <label>Job</label>
            <input 
                type="text" 
                name="job" 
                value={job} 
                onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        </form>
        <input 
    type="button" 
    value="Submit" 
    onClick={this.submitForm} />
      </div>
    );
 }
}

export default Form;

class Table extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const {characters, removeCharacter} = this.props;
    return(
      <table>
        <TableHeader />
        <TableBody fillTheData = {characters} removeCharacter= {removeCharacter} />
      </table>
    )
  }
}

const TableHeader = () => { 
    return (
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Job</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    );
}
```

Right now, we have a cool Table component, but the data is being hard-coded. One of the big deals about React is how it handles data, and it does so with properties, referred to as props, and with state. First, we’ll focus on handling data with props.

Then let’s move all that data to an array of objects, as if we were bringing in a JSON-based API. We’ll have to create this array inside our render().

Comment: have you fixed the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The `handleChange` method of `Form` component is declaring a constant named `job` which doesn't exist in `event.target` object and it is setting the state with `value` variable which doesn't exists in that scope.

So change

`const{name,job} = event.target;`

to

`const{name,value} = event.target;`

your code will just work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. However, after I changing the thing, it still does not work. :( Pretty strange

Comment: have you replace `job` with `value` on that line, because it's working fine on my side

Comment: Yes. I changed the original code to const {name, value} = event.target  The problem is that there is nothing shown up ..

Comment: found the issue you are exporting the `Form` component as default it should be `App` component, take a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/820kl1p4v9)

Comment: Gotcha. I do exactly what you told me, but there must be a bug inside my code.

Comment: got it, you should include 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>

to your html file so it can compile react code to ES5 and change js preprocessor from `None` to `Babel` and remove the all export statements from js file

Comment: Got it. I do not know why. It is so weird. It still not working

Comment: copy babel source link from [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/babel-standalone), complete link is not being paste in the comment, sorry about that

Comment: Last quick question: I noticed that the form and submit button are on the left side of the screen. If I want to syle it in the middle. Should I use .containerForWhole {margin: auto}  (But this one is not working). Feel free to check inside my codepen link: https://codepen.io/Logenli/pen/wQPrJo

Comment: use `text-align: center;` style on your `form` wrapping `div`, and If you are satisfied with answer please accept and vote answer.